# Selenium command level reporting using testNG

Tags: selenium, command, reporting, testng

I’m new to Selenium WebDriver, Currently working on reporting testcases & test suits using TestNG (import org.testng.Reporter)on eclipse, At present TestNG produces high level reporting features for test cases ,methods & suites on test- output folder, similar to this --> http://testng.org/test-output/index.html.

I'm looking for a way to have following in the report created by testNG,

- All selenium commands executed in my test method(s) should be displayed in index.html &
- Failed screenshots for the relevant failure command with the reports, something similar to loggingSelenium ---> http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/samples/sampleResultSuccess.html

The reason I prefer this way is its easier, because this way I know exactly what selenium commands which were executed , I would have correct information what goes wrong, and when this occurs and the input parameters belong to specific selenium commands.

Is it possible in testNG?

Comment: If your requirement is to provide a better reporting, why dont you create a simple framework which consists of wrapper methods around selenium commands?Like instead of click you should call myframework.click() which should have the logic to log the details you need..